# Long running SQL scripts in API(30 minutes) handling in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET based Web API hosted in Azure App service. I have an heavy SQL script inside an API that I have to execute and return the response. The SQL script runs for 30+ minutes and results in the timeout of API(max timeout in App service for an API call is 230 seconds only). Is there a way I can trigger the SQL script in background while I could return an immediate response and return actual response after completion. Please suggest a way that I can handle within the API project itself and no external components.

Comment: You can use a `Task` or a `Thread` to run the SQL process, but if you return a response you aren't going to just be able to send out another response when it finishes like you would in the normal request/response flow. You could however send an email message or a push notification if they are working through a web interface to the user when the sql operation completes. I doubt a user would want to wait 30 minutes for the UI to get confirmation on whether the process finished or not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you mentionned "App service" so i think you are some familiar with azure services,i would suggest to create a durable functions using Azure Functions , this will let you to return repsonse instatly and keeping check for response until the request finish the work.

Otherwise always there is an old school solution , so you can  :

1. Create console app  that run the query and save response to a file.
2. Create an API that consume the file and return response. Add your.
3. console app as a job(task) within your app service.

Comment: Depending on your plan azure functions has also a limited runtime. e.g. consumption plan functions are limited to 10 minutes maximum.

Comment: yes it's normal , but you can you appservice plan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge, and i decided to go with [azure batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-dotnet)

So in my WebApi I create the batch pool, batch job and task. The Azure batch task will execute the sql query and write the status and result into an azure storage from where I can read this inside the WebApi. After it has finished I clean up my Azure batch resource from the Web API, meaning delete the pool and job if they are no longer needed.